# Angular - using a variable as type in inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have this child class :

```
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  protected model = ChildModel;
}
```

In the parent, I would like to use the child's model as a type for the response of a http call, and for the promise !

```
getData(): Promise<this.model> { // doesn't work
  return this.http.get(this.url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response as this.model) // doesn't work
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use type [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

```
export class ChildService extends ParentService<ChildModel> {
}

class ParentService<TType> {
   getData(): Promise<TType> {
      return this.http.get(this.url)
     .toPromise()
         .then(response => response as TType)
         .catch(this.handleError);
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks awesome !

Comment: What if another function in the same class needs to use another type ?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo can you give me an example? You can use more than one type for generics `<TTypeA, TTypeB, TTypeC>`. Methods can also have their own local types `getData<DataType>: Promise<DataType> {...}`